# Does MDNS discovery have a maximum number of devices that it can discover?

Tags: c#, .net, mdns

Our application uses MDNS discovery to populate screens with device data. We have acquired a customer with an unusually large number of devices on their network. We are finding that when the number of devices exceeds 90, MDNS discovery fails.

Has anybody else run into a limit like this? We're trying to figure out if it is worth the effort to send someone onsite to track down the issue, or if this is just a limitation of the system and we need to recommend that they not have more than 90 devices on a single subnet.

Our application uses a home-brewed C#, framework .NET 4.8 project to do discovery.

Comment: Are you sure the devices are on the same subnet? Larger organizations also tend to use more than one subnet by segmenting their networks across multiple vlans, and mDNS discovery does not work across vlans without a special gateway. Even if that's not the exact issue, you might find using an mDNS Gateway useful for this issue.

Comment: Assuming they are actually on the same subnet and VLAN: once you start hitting 100+ devices on a network/VLAN you anyway run into chatty broadcasting issues ie everyone is broadcasting to everyone all at once. Recommendation is normally to segment into VLANs or for public networks to use a Private VLAN to isolate clients completely.